# Is there a language without pointers and explicit object size management but with explicit object deletion?

Tags: memory-management, programming-languages

High level language coders usually think that the problem high-level GC-powered languages solve is need to delete allocated objects manually but forget about buffer overflow and pointer arithmetic mistakes mess. Is there a language that does the second but leaves the first in the hands of the developer? Something like Java/C#/etc featuring a 'delete' keyword?

Answer (score 1):

Yep. [Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28programming_language%29). Pascal is not garbage collected. It has new and freemem to allocate and deallocate memory respectively. Though pointer arithmetic is possible, it is not needed for array access like in C. There is a built-in array type and string type in several flavors of Pascal and many implementations do array bounds checking.

Also, this is slightly off topic, but you might be interested in languages with RAII memory management. Some RAII languages do memory management for you, and thus don't require you to explicitly allocate and deallocate memory. However, they do so with object lifetime bound to a lexical scope instead of reference counting. Under this strategy deconstructors make more sense.

I'm not sure if it's explicit allocation and deallocation you want or if it's a stronger understanding of when memory is allocated, even if it happens automatically and the ability to trigger deconscrutor methods. If it's the latter you're interested in, then check out [D](http://dlang.org/) perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to [mmachenry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22727713),

Objects in Java and C# (excluding arrays) tend to be small, because these objects typically contain references to other objects - they don't literally reserve space for the field objects to be included into the parent object's memory layout. This is different from C++.

Both Java and C# have implemented a form of cooperative deterministic object cleanup. This deterministic cleanup is intended to take care of other types resources, not about freeing the object's memory.

- In C# this is known as [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx).
- In Java this is known as [Closeable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html).

To make sure that they will be called at the end of some code,

- In C#, call IDisposable.Dispose() in a `finally` block. Alternatively, initialize such object at the beginning of a `using` block, provided that the object never leaves the scope of that block.
- In Java, call Closeable.Close() in a `finally` block.

These techniques are found to be necessary for these languages to interact with objects that are:

- Implemented in a different language (environment) that requires explicit cleanup, such as Microsoft COM, or
- Represents network, database or operating-systems resources, or some other resources that are capacity-controlled.

Arrays are a different matter because they can get huge (megabytes to gigabytes). If an application uses a lot of temporary fixed-size arrays, it might make sense for one to implement an array pool. I used this technique in my most recent C# project for image processing. (Remark: My array pool is not a singleton.)